# using newFixedThreadPool results some weird problems

Tags: java, multithreading

In a multi-thread program, I've used newFixedThreadPool with a 10 thread number.

The first problem I've faced with is the number of threads which are active on the system which is logged by "ps huH p PID | wc -l" shows a much larger number of active threads in the system which is 80 threads. Additionally, a program which executes threads reads messages from a queue and then provokes each thread by the message.

The second problem is the java heap space exception. Actually, it occurs after a period of the program execution.

Eventually, the last problem is that, while no messages could be or even read by the threads from the queue but the output of the threads reveal they are active and are processing some data.

According to above-articulated problems, my questions are listed below:

- isn't it an assured rule that newFixedThreadPool(n) has at most n number of threads simultaneously?
- if the number of threads is fixed, then why the GC exception arrises?
- how is the last problem possible?

Also, I tested the

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor((10, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2 * 10));
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the aforementioned problem solved. I'm just going to describe each part of the question: 
"ps huH p PID | wc -l": this command does not get the number of actual threads are still running using ThreadPool, but shows the total number of OS level threads for a job.

newFixedThreadPool(n): has an unbounded blocking queue which means that, as the input of your program is available, then it would create one object and adds that to that blocking queue. As a result, the memory problem can raise when there is a huge number of input elements.

Finally, the below option did not work because the default implementation for ArrayBlockingQueue has a offer method that is used for inserting new object to it.

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor((10, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2 * 10));
```

As its name shows, offer method tries to add the requested object to the end of the arrayBlockingQueue. Otherwise, if the ArrayBlockingQueue's put method be used, the problem would be solved. To do so, I extended the ArrayBlockingQueue and overrides it's offer method by calling its put method in the offer's method blocking queue.